# When i click on specific tag i want it to show its unique value but it keeps showing only the first value

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps, addeventlistener

The output will always be goodbye even when clicked on hello

How to identify and get unique values from the specific tags?

```js
addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.id == 'democlass') {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
});
```

```css
#democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="democlass" value="Goodbye">Goodbye </h1>
<h1 id="democlass" value="Hello ">Hello </h1>

<p>Click the button to display the value of the id of the h1 element.</p>


<p id="demo">Here lies new text</p>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. No two elements can share the same ID. I suggest switching to classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IDs must be unique. No two elements can share the same ID. If you want to group elements I suggest switching to classes instead.
2. In addition I don't think the value attribute on an `H1` element is valid HTML, so select the text content instead.

This example adds an event listener to the document but doesn't use classes. It checks the `nodeName` instead.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const { target: { nodeName } } = e;
  if (nodeName === 'H1') {
    const value = e.target.textContent;
    demo.textContent = value;
  }
});
```

```css
#democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Goodbye</h1>
<h1>Hello</h1>

<p>Click the button to display the value of the class attribute of the h1 element.</p>

<p id="demo">Here lies new text</p>
```

Instead of setting an event listener at document level you might want to just target the headings. In this example I've used classes:

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
const h1s = document.querySelectorAll('.democlass');

h1s.forEach(h1 => h1.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false));

function handleClick(e) {
  const value = e.target.textContent;
  demo.textContent = value;
}
```

```css
#democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="democlass">Goodbye</h1>
<h1 class="democlass">Hello</h1>

<p>Click the button to display the value of the class attribute of the h1 element.</p>

<p id="demo">Here lies new text</p>
```

But you might not want to add an event listener to each heading. What if, instead of two headings, you had 100. Well, you can take advantage of the fact that events "bubble up" the DOM. [`Event delegation`](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) allows you to add an event listener to a parent element to "catch" events as they bubble up.

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const { target: { textContent } } = e;
  demo.textContent = textContent;
}
```

```css
#democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="democlass">Goodbye</h1>
  <h1 class="democlass">Hello</h1>
</div>

<p>Click the button to display the value of the class attribute of the h1 element.</p>

<p id="demo">Here lies new text</p>
```

Comment: I do not recommend to add event listeners to each element. Also if you decide to add any other child  tag to the H1, your first code will not work if you click the child tag. Also my code used data-attribute which is certainly valid HTML

Answer (score 1):

1. IDs must be unique - Use class
2. Delegate from something nearer that window - which is what you do now when you only do `addEventListener`
3. Use data attributes instead of the value attribute which belongs to form fields. Alternatively use the textContent which is the same in your code as your attribute

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("h1"); // in case you add tags to the H1s
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains('democlass')) {
    var x = tgt.dataset.value; // or tgt.textContent
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
});
```

```css
#democlass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<h1 class="democlass" data-value="Goodbye">Goodbye </h1>
<h1 class="democlass" data-value="Hello ">Hello </h1>
</div>
<p>Click the header to display the value of the id of the h1 element.</p>


<p id="demo">Here lies new text</p>
```